# How to access my webserver from the host machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, webserver, port-forwarding

My host OS is Gentoo, guest OS - Fedora. I have a web server on Fedora on port 8686 and it works perfectly on guest OS, but I can't access it on my host OS.
I tried to use bridged network (then I got 2 different IPs to my guest and host machines from router) and NAT (then I forward port 8686). Nothing helped, but SSH works nicely when using both NAT and bridge (even if using the same port). How to solve this issue?

Comment: You should add the guest OS entry in `\etc\hosts` file of the host OS.

Comment: Did you check iptables on the guest OS using `iptables -nvL`?

Comment: >[...] but I can't access it on my host OS.

Comment: Take a look at this Q if you're attempting to use NAT: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12885/how-to-reach-a-vbox-guest-from-host-when-using-nat-networking

Comment: @mtak, I disabled iptables on the guest OS

Answer (score 0):

If ssh works nicely in both NAT and bridge and on the same port as web-server, then problem is in your web-server configuration.
Check what ip address your web-server binds to. You can check it with netstat utility (you must run it with root privileges):
    `netstat -nltp`