# VBox Nat SSH still failing after forward (debian)

Tags: debian, ssh, virtualbox

I have the following VBox...

[image]

I check and ssh is running

[image]

So I try to forward the request

[image]

and then I to ssh from host...

```
$node % ssh -v -p 40 me@127.0.1.1
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /.../.ssh/config
debug1: /.../.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.1.1 [127.0.1.1] port 40.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.1.1 port 40: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 127.0.1.1 port 40: Operation timed out
```

What am I missing?

## Update

I have confirmed it works with bridged but I want to use NAT

Comment: Please copy&paster text to your question **as text** instead of showing screenshots.

Comment: ? Then it looks unreadable IMHO. And it is just console logs so not sure where this helps

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 Copy&paste the text into the question and format it as a code block.

Comment: Bodo is correct; it makes it easier for answerers (and future readers) to compare, troubleshoot, and answer your question if it has text *as text*. Thank you!

Comment: @Bodo I know how to do that but it still looks like crap @JeffSchaller I would get that if it was code but you aren't going to be able to recreate my `ip a` command locally

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox you can't access a guest directly from the host when using a NAT'ed network interface.

A common solution for this, is to use bridged mode or create a second *host only* interface for host to guest communication.

However, it seems that setting up port forwarding should be possible if you require a NAT'ed interface, as you have mentioned in the comments, but it seems that you might have an error in the forwarding rule.

The *ip* command show the guest ip to be: 10.**0.2**.15
But in the forwarding rule you used: 10.**2.0**.15 as ip address.

Comment: Thanks but that seems to contradict posts like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12885/how-to-reach-a-vbox-guest-from-host-when-using-nat-networking.

Comment: @Jackie, I agree if the accepted answer there is correct? I have never been able to make it work. I would agree with: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12886/311645
But I might be wrong.

Comment: thanks but even that answer says "You may configure special port forwarding rules to reach the boxes" (talks about how you cant access the whole network but I don't need that). So I think there is a way to do it so technically your answer is wrong (at least given my question) the question is if it is wrong, how do I get it to work.

Comment: Just realized I posted the wrong link initially https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145997/trying-to-ssh-to-local-vm-ubuntu-with-putty

Comment: From that post it sure seems to be possible.
It seems that your forwarding rule might be wrong.
I have updated my answer.

Comment: Good catch let me confirm

Comment: No dice I changed it to match but it is still not working.